# TYPO3 fe_user how login user via php code?

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and extension femanager.

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = '';
$info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
$user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $username);
$loginData = array('uname' => $username, 'uident' => $password, 'status' => 'login');

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->forceSetCookie = TRUE;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();

$loginSuccess = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->compareUident($user, $loginData);
```

this code does't work. error:

```
PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to In2code\Femanager\Utility\LogUtility::log() must be an instance of In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User, boolean given, called in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3conf/ext/feusersplus/Classes/Controller/NewController.php on line 91 and defined in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3conf/ext/femanager/Classes/Utility/LogUtility.php line 48
```

Is it hard code? May be exists better way ?

Do you know how login user via php code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `$loginData['uname']` i use the email as username, you can simply change it with the username it self (`$user->getUsername()`);

**Class StandardLogin:**

```
<?php
namespace Ads\Adsmanager\Authentication\Login;

/**
 * Standard Login of users
 *
 * @author Andrei Todorut <todorutac@gmail.com>
 */
class StandardLogin extends \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Authentication\FrontendUserAuthentication implements LoginInterface
{    
    /**
     * 
     * @param \Ads\Adsmanager\Domain\Model\User $user
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function login(\Ads\Adsmanager\Domain\Model\User $user)
    {
        $passwordProcessor = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Salt\\PhpassSalt');

        $loginData = array(
            'uname' => $user->getEmail(), //usernmae
            'uident' => $user->getPassword(), //password
            'status' => 'login'
        );


        $this->checkPid = false;
        $info = $this->getAuthInfoArray();
        $info['db_user']['username_column'] = 'email';

        $user_db = $this->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $loginData['uname']);
        if ($user_db && $passwordProcessor->checkPassword($user->getPassword(), $user_db['password'])) {

            $this->setSession($user_db);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private function setSession($user_db) 
    {

        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user_db);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $user_db;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'fe_typo_user', $user_db);
    }
}
```

**Your action controller:**

```
<?php 
//...
//stuff
public function loginAction(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\User $user)
{
    $login = new StandardLogin();
    $login->login($user);
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try ti!

Comment: I check all your code. All work. But this code:

        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user_db);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $user_db;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'fe_typo_user', $user_db);

don't working, session not creating

Comment: Could you have a check please in Local configuration in [FE][logonSecurityLevel] , should be normal not rsa if you don't have SSL cert.

Comment: I set it normal, man) But in front-end it still looks like the user not logined, I sure problem in session. Because  here $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user    I have user. I have clear all cache, not results

Comment: Do you enter in the `true` of this  `if ($user_db && $passwordProcessor->checkPassword($user->getPassword(), $user_db['password'])) {` ?

Comment: Yes, Andrei, I checked it! I sure, the method setSession calling!

Comment: Can you do it? I need help, really I can't fix it (

Comment: Yes, i just get to the pc :)

Comment: Do you use `username` or `email` for the `username` `field`? You have to pay attention also on this    `$info['db_user']['username_column'] = 'email';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144728/discussion-between-andrei-todorut-and-mikael).

Answer (score 2):

> Call it with username as a parameter

```
function loginUser($username)
{
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = '';
    $info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
    $user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $username);
    $loginData = array('uname' => $username, 'uident' => $user['password'], 'status' => 'login');

    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->forceSetCookie = TRUE;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);

    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
    $setSessionCookieMethod = $reflection->getMethod('setSessionCookie');
    $setSessionCookieMethod->setAccessible(TRUE);
    $setSessionCookieMethod->invoke($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);

    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
    $session_data = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
    $loginSuccess = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->compareUident($user, $loginData);

    setcookie('fe_typo_user', $session_data['ses_id'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    setcookie('nc_staticfilecache', 'fe_typo_user_logged_in', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo3 recently changed it's Cookie policy to not create a fe_typo_user by default (due to GDPR/DSGVO). The other solutions no longer work since they missed "start()".

The below function works as expected:

```
public function loginUser($username, $password)
{
    $loginData = array(
        'uname' => $username,
        'uident_text' => $password,
        'status' => 'login'
    );

    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
    $info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
    $userAuth = $this->objectManager->get(FrontendUserAuthentication::class);
    $user = $userAuth->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $loginData['uname']);

    if ($user) {
        $userAuth->checkPid = false;
        $isValidLoginData = $this->saltedPasswordService->compareUident($user, $loginData);

        if (!$isValidLoginData) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->forceSetCookie = TRUE;
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->dontSetCookie = false;
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->start();
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('dummy', TRUE);
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->loginUser = 1;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It lacks serious status handling. If I improve it further it can be found here: https://gist.github.com/tserowski/8572c2314f7f909f31248a9ad0023509

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss an `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData();` and a `$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->storeSessionData();` to save the changes.

I have only an old (TYPO3 4.5) example, where it works:

```
$user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getRawUserByName($username);

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData();
$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->setKey("ses", "do_redirect", 0);
$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->storeSessionData();
```

Comment: Have added an old example. Have actually not tried in newer versions.

Comment: Thank you) but it does't working in 7.6.18, after this code $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid']    -   return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size.
Works for TYPO3 V10.

```
/**
 * User sign in.
 *
 * @param string $suppliedPassword - The just-supplied password
 * @param string $storedPassword  - The stored user password
 * @param int $permanentLogin   - Whether to log the user permanently.
 *        - Requires setting $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['permalogin'] to 1
 *          in your ext_localconf file.
 *        - Optionally, set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['lifetime'] to how long
 *          you want the permanent session to last.
 * @param int $uid - The UID of the user you want to login.
 * @param null|mixed $userSessionData - User's data you want to persist.
 */
public function logon(string $suppliedPassword, string $storedPassword, int $permanentLogin, int $uid, $userSessionData = NULL): void {

    /**
     * Password.
     */
    if ($this->passwordIsAuthentic($suppliedPassword, $storedPassword)) {

        #Log in user
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->is_permanent = $permanentLogin;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession(['uid' => $uid]);

        if($userSessionData){

            /**
             * @tip You can change the key name '__USER__' to whatever you like.
             */
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('__USER__', $userSessionData);
        }

        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->loginSessionStarted = 1;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setSessionCookie();

        /**
         * @Note $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser is deprecated in favor of 
         * $context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', 'isLoggedIn');
         */
    }
}

/**
 * Check password here
 *
 * @param string $suppliedPassword
 * @param string $storedPassword
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function passwordIsAuthentic(string $suppliedPassword, string $storedPassword): bool {

    $saltFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\PasswordHashFactory::class);
    $invalidPasswordHashException = NULL;

    try {
        $hashInstance = $saltFactory->get($storedPassword, TYPO3_MODE);
        if (($hashInstance instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\PasswordHashInterface) && $hashInstance->checkPassword($suppliedPassword, $storedPassword)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    } catch (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\InvalidPasswordHashException $invalidPasswordHashException) {

        // Get a hashed password instance for the hash stored in db of this user
        return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```